# How I can retrieve geometry column without including the CRS object

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I am using the PostGIS geometry in the PostgreSQL db in my application. I am using sequelize ORM to get the data from the db. When I get the geometry field data it returns the data like mentioned below:

```
“location”: {
                    “crs”: {
                        “type”: “name”,
                        “properties”: {
                            “name”: “EPSG:4326”
                        }
                    },
                    “type”: “Point”,
                    “coordinates”: [
                        31.0120136,
                        -155.3959561
                    ]
```

In the response I am getting the CRS along with the geometry data. I do not need this CRS. I need only the geometry data like below

```
“location”: [
                    “type”: “Point”,
                    “coordinates”: [
                        31.0120136,
                        -155.3959561
                    ]
```

How I can retrieve the geometry column without including the CRS object using the sequlize in my node app?